# date-fns formatRelative RangeError: Invalid time value when using basic new Date() js function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, date-fns

I'm making a todo list app in react, and want to use formatRelative for the date created. When the todo is created, I set a new Date() to a variable, and then set that date as todo.created. It is then stored in the App's state and subsequently sent to a firebase server for storage. However, when I reload the page, I get the RangeError: Invalid time value for when the todo list tries to render.

Here is some code:

```
// creating the todo:
submitHandler = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    this.props.addTodo({
        id: this.props.nextId(),
        title: document.querySelector(".modal-title-input").value,
        description: document.querySelector(".modal-desc-input").value,
        due: document.querySelector(".modal-due-date-input").value,
        priority: document.querySelector(".modal-priority-input").value,
        created: today,
        done: false,
    });

// when the todo is rendered:
const todo = this.props.todo;
const today = new Date();
console.log(isValid(today, todo.created))    // true, true
console.log(formatRelative(today, todo.created));  // RangeError
```

Comment: What's the value of `todo.created` when it's being rendered?

Comment: According to the Date-fns documentation, [*isValid*](https://date-fns.org/v2.14.0/docs/isValid) only takes one argument, so `isValid(today, todo.created)` only checks the first argument, not the second. You need to include what *addTodo* is doing (i.e. you need to include enough code to reproduce the error).

Comment: Thank you! So it turns out the second argument was *not* valid. This is what I'm getting back with todo.created: t {seconds: 1592164876, nanoseconds: 508000000}

Comment: Then you need to do something like `new Date(todo.created.seconds * 1e3 + todo.created.nanoseconds / 1e6)` (i.e. convert the values to milliseconds) which gives "2020-06-14T20:01:16.508Z".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @RobG. I was able to fix the issue once you guys helped me realize the problem was how the object was being received back from Firebase. I was able to fix the problem by simply using the toDate() function:

```
// declared before the class
const fireLibrary = db.collection("todos").doc("library");

// inside the class
componentDidMount() {
    fireLibrary.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists && doc.data().todosLibrary) {
            const lib = doc.data().todosLibrary.map(item => {
                item.created = item.created.toDate()
                return item
            })
            this.setState({ todosLibrary: lib });
        }
    });
}
```